# How do I add HTML to a ListItem in ASP/VB.net?

Tags: html, vb.net, listitem

If I use this code on my aspx page:

```
<asp:BulletedList ID="listClientContacts" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem><b>My Name</b></asp:ListItem>
 </asp:BulletedList>
```

The text renders as literal `<b>My Name</b>` instead of making the text bold. The same thing happens if I try to add a list item from the VB side of things:

```
 Dim li As ListItem = New ListItem("<b>My Name</b>")
 Me.listClientContacts.Items.Add(li)
```

Is there a way to add HTML to a ListItem in ASP, or is there a better way to dynamically generate a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your list from a data-source?  If so, then just use a repeater

```
<ul>
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" DataSourceID="sqlDataSource1">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <li><b><asp:Literal runat="server" Text=<%#Eval("Field") %>></asp:Literal></b></li>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</ul>
```